# NetworkManager-configured dnsmasq failing to forward requests

Tags: ubuntu, dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I use Lubuntu 17.04, on which the NetworkManager service (subsystem?) performs some configuration actions when I connect to a new network. One of these is (re)setting the `/etc/resolv.conf` file to:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search some-local-domain-here
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

at least that's what I get when DHCP is used. There's a `dnsmasq` instance which listens on the local host (more information about it provided below.)

Now, on some networks, and pretty consistently, names cannot be resolved in this state of affairs; but if I replace the `nameserver` line with the actual nameserver's address I got from the DHCP lease (`/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-blah-blah.wlan0.lease`) - resolution works fine.

**Questions:**

- What could be the cause of this problem?
- How can I force the NetworkManager-configured dnsmasq to actually forward name resolution requests to the DHCP-provided DNS server? (Note that it *sometimes* does this already - when this problem doesn't manifest)

---

**Additional information:**

The local DNS server is a `dnsmasq` instance, with the following command line:

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

The configuration directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` has a single file, whose contents are:

```
# Tell any system-wide dnsmasq instance to make sure to bind to interfaces
# instead of listening on 0.0.0.0
# WARNING: changes to this file will get lost if network-manager is removed.
bind-interfaces
```

Comment: I don't know why dnsmasq completely fails to forward your queries, for me i noticed it was introducing a significant delay to dns queries and also i knew the nameserver in LAN distributed by dhcp was golden so i just wanted to disabled dnsmasq and found the following which worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/627900

Comment: @ZaphodB: I think that qualifies as an answer (albeit not the "perfect" answer).

Comment: this worked for me: `apt-get remove libnss-mdns`  https://askubuntu.com/a/81807/17002

Answer (score 2):

Most modern Debian-related distributions tend to now use the `/sbin/resolvconf` tool to configure `/etc/resolv.conf` instead of editing it directly. This tool will keep track of DNS server information received for each interface, and it will prioritize the DNS server settings according to the order specified in file `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order`.

This way, you can get one set of DNS server settings when switching on Wi-Fi, another set when plugging in a network cable, a third one when starting up a VPN connection... and not end up with a messed-up configuration when you shut these down in a not-strictly-reverse order. Also, in this situation you can get two different mechanisms (e.g. NetworkManager and `dnsmasq`) vying for the control of the real `/etc/resolv.conf`, which might be

However, `resolvconf` is an optional package. If `/sbin/resolvconf` does not exist on your system, your `/etc/resolv.conf` might be under direct control of NetworkManager. But it looks like most of the scripting in the `dnsmasq` package is written assuming that `/sbin/resolvconf` exists - so without it you're relying on fallbacks which might not cover all situations adequately. You might want to try install it with `apt-get install resolvconf` or something similar and see how the DNS settings behave with it installed.

If you don't have the `resolvconf` package installed, I'm afraid NetworkManager does it all on its own - and in that case troubleshooting would require reading the source code of NetworkManager to see how it actually decides which DNS settings to use. `resolvconf` is far less opaque.

After `dnsmasq` starts up on (L)Ubuntu Zesty (17.04), its start-up scripts will run this command (assuming that the `resolvconf` package is installed):

```
echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" | /sbin/resolvconf -a lo.dnsmasq
```

This tells `/sbin/resolvconf` that a new DNS name server has become available on interface `lo`, and it will update the real `/etc/resolv.conf`.

While this (or any) update of `/etc/resolv.conf` is happening, `/sbin/resolvconf` will run all scripts located in `/etc/resolvconf/update.d`. One of them is `/etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq` which is supposed to take up a list of all non-local DNS servers known to `resolvconf` at the time, and push them to `/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf`, which is apparently the DNS server list that `dnsmasq` should be using.

Once every second, `dnsmasq` is supposed to check the modification time of `/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` and update its configuration.

However, your dnsmasq command line indicates that you may have made some changes to the default settings: you might want to replace the dnsmasq option `--no-resolv` with `--resolv-file=/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf`... or just remove any NetworkManager or resolv.conf-related customizations, since it looks like the default settings of `dnsmasq` have been designed to integrate with NetworkManager and `resolvconf` in an appropriate way.

If the `resolvconf` tool is in use, you'll find the DNS server settings supplied by all the various possible sources in directory `/run/resolvconf/interface/`. The contents of each file will be similar to the real `/etc/resolv.conf`. The name of the file will refer to the source of the DNS server information, whether it is a static or DHCP configuration of a particular network interface, or NetworkManager in general, or the start-up scripts of a local DNS server.

Earlier, I mentioned a command line that will be executed at `dnsmasq` start-up if `/sbin/resolvconf` is installed. If you want to temporarily undo that (to test if DNS works if the local `dnsmasq` is bypassed), you can do it with this command:

```
resolvconf -d lo.dnsmasq
```

When you do that, the DNS settings of your highest-priority active network interface should take over in the real `/etc/resolv.conf`.

If you want to make `dnsmasq` startup scripts stop replacing the active DNS settings with the "nameserver 127.0.0.1" line (whether for troubleshooting or for other reasons), apparently adding `DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo` to `/etc/default/dnsmasq` will achieve that.

But since your nameserver line has value 127.0.1.1 instead, it is probably directly written by NetworkManager, and I have no clue how to fix that if `resolvconf` is out of the picture.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that NetworkManager uses dnsmasq.

Comment: Yes... and I used https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/all/dnsmasq/download to download the `dnsmasq` package for your Lubuntu version and took a peek inside it. Try running `sudo /sbin/resolvconf -d lo.dnsmasq` and see if it restores your DHCP-provided DNS settings. It won't persist over a reboot, but if this works it will tell me where to look at next.

Comment: Looks like adding `DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo` into `/etc/default/dnsmasq` might be a persistent fix.

Comment: Can you: 1. Explain the last comment? 2. Remove the part about Bind from the answer and 3. Move your extra text from the comments into the body of the answer?